# DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, service-broker

I have inherited a few scripts that are pumped through a c#.NET custom app to update a SQL2005 SP3 database.  One of these scripts does a deletion on a user table called `msw_timer_task`, based on a filtered join to `sys.conversation_endpoints`.

Here is the SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS , ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, 
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
/*
SELECT name, is_ansi_nulls_on, is_ansi_padding_on, is_ansi_warnings_on, 
    is_arithabort_on, is_concat_null_yields_null_on, is_numeric_roundabort_on, 
    is_quoted_identifier_on
FROM sys.databases where name = db_name()
*/
print 'clean up unattended time tasks'
delete from msw_timer_task where timer_task_id in (
    select m.timer_task_id
    from msw_timer_task m
        left join sys.conversation_endpoints c on 
                c.conversation_handle = m.conversation_handle
    where c.conversation_handle is null and m.state = 'WAITING')
```

This script errors with the following error message:

```
ERROR:
Severity 16, state 1 error number 1934 line 8 of proc on server SomeSillySrv:
DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings:
'ANSI_NULLS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or
indexes on computed columns and/or query notifications and/or xml data type methods.
```

I have done a lot of Googling on the issue, and have played around a lot with the set statement in an attempt to get it to work.  In testing, in SSMS, the script did not produce an error, at least not before shipping it.

I am not sure if I am missing something, but it seems that the settings are not properly set when run through the app.

Am I missing something in the script?

Comment: What happens if you just remove `ANSI_NULLS ,` from the `SET` command?

Comment: @phil - Just to clarify, you mean removing just the `ANSI_NULLS`, leaving the other in place? I assume because you suspect the `.Net SqlClient Data Provider` might cause different behaviour?

Comment: SSMS defaults it to ON, .net provider to OFF. User profiler to see if the SET is being ignored or overridden http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: @gbn : Using profiler, I found that the script is being run as is above, overriding with the SET.  What I have found that is interesting though, is that my table has a primary xml index.

Comment: "line 8 of proc on server SomeSillySrv" < if the code is in a stored procedure, note that `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` settings are stored with the procedure definition. You can't override them with `SET` statements in the procedure. Script the procedure to see the settings in effect when it was created, or use `OBJECTPROPERTYEX`.